# PHP variable = get_the_post_thumbnail_url outputting without slashes

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

In a custom shortcode function, I'm grabbing the featured image URL:

```
$text_slider_testimonial_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($single->ID);
```

If I echo `$text_slider_testimonial_img` immediately I see the correct image URL: `//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/splitbanner1.jpg`

When I pass this variable to a function, and that function uses:

```
$text_slider_content .= "<div class='text_slider_testimonial' style='background-size: cover; background-image: url('". $text_slider_testimonial_img ."')>";
return $text_slider_content;
```

the style component of the above is output as:

```
style="background-size: cover; background-image: url(" localhost:3000="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2021="" 03="" splitbanner1.jpg')="">
```

Why are the slashes being stripped out, and the `=""` being added?

Help appreciated.

[Here is the wider code context (pastebin.com)](https://pastebin.com/d0NxW40K).

Comment: That function isn't escaping properly, I don't see any escaping used

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that @TomJNowell. Please explain for me?

Comment: Something else is wrong here. Something not shown in the question here is converting parts of the URL into attributes for some reason. Try disabling plugins, changing the theme, and narrowing down the cause further.

Comment: Thanks @Howdy_McGee. I've deactivated all plugins except Advanced Custom Fields (required to produce the content) and the issue remains. The current theme contains the shortcode in question. I've added a pastebin.com link in the question to provide a wider code context.

Comment: You want to escape the variable so that the quotes are encoded properly, but no escaping is added. Escaping is a fundamental security practice and one that's left out of most tutorials, and forgotten by most developers. If you want to put a value in a set of strings that itself contains a set of strings, it needs to be encoded so it doesn't break, and escaped so it is secure

Comment: Also, you should use `WP_Query` to fetch posts, not raw SQL queries. Eitherway the cause of your problems is that you do not apply escaping to any of your variables when you put them into HTML strings

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, I've changed my code to `<div class="text_slider_testimonial" style="background-size: cover; background-image: url("' . esc_url($text_slider_testimonial_img) . '")>'` but the same issue remains. I used [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) as a reference.

Comment: @SRDMH this mangled HTML, is this present in the output that the server sends, or, is this in the browser after the javascript has run? How did you eliminate javascript as a possible issue? Did you check via `view-source` or `curl`/`wget` the original unmodified markup? There is nothing in your code that would turn a URL into attributes like that

Comment: Also, you really, really shouldn't be using raw SQL to fetch posts, ***use `WP_Query` instead***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the line with below line may solve the issue.

```php
$text_slider_content .= '<div class="text_slider_testimonial" style="background-size: cover; background-image: url('. $text_slider_testimonial_img .');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the line with following should solve the issue:

```
$text_slider_content .= "<div class='text_slider_testimonial' style='background-size: cover; background-image: url($text_slider_testimonial_img);>";
```